# Installing a large size apk application on Android phone

Tags: android

I have an application which is of size 130MB. when i try to install its displaying insufficient memory error. but i have around 170MB left in available space in internal memory. How can i Install this app? The size of the app is large because it contains many media files. In Motorolla droid its getting installed. but on Nexus One its giving this error.

Comment: same problem facing by me..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584297/error-in-installation-of-an-application-on-sd-card-in-android-sdk-2-2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not package the media files in the app itself.  It would be better to put the media files on a server and have the app download the media files to the sdcard.  This is a common thing for Android apps to do.  If you install that large of an app, that means you have much less room to install other apps.  If you have users other than yourself, they will despise that the app is so large.

Another option, is to [install Froyo on the Nexus One](http://androidandme.com/2010/05/news/how-to-manually-install-android-2-2-on-your-nexus-one/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+androidandme+(Android+and+Me)) and alter the app [so it can be installed on the sd card](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html).