# Android - Increase ROM Size

Tags: android

as i am facing problem here: [Installing application on SD-card in Android sdk 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584297/installing-application-on-sd-card-in-android-sdk-2-2) , regarding application installation.

In above question, you can view the image in which "Internal Phone Storage" is showing where only 43.38 MB is showing , and in latest android phone, i know it is coming with higher space, i have seen 13.45 GB in Samsung Galaxy Android Phone.

But Right now, i am using HTC Hero, so my questions are:

1. is there any way to increase ROM size without any side-effect?
2. How do i increase ROM Size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.

[ROM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-only_memory) isn't application space, it is programmed at the factory and usually there is very little of it, just enough [to boot up your device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROM_image).

Comment: then where does the application installed and which memory it using ? i have read an article here: http://androidforums.com/sprint-htc-hero/13022-ram-rom-what.html , where it is written that ROM has 2 parts: one for OS and the rest of the part is for the Application usage

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way to increase ROM size without any side-effect?

Not really. If you can deploy an alternative firmware (e.g., Cyanogen), you may wind up with more free space in the on-board flash.

> How do i increase ROM Size?

Buy a new phone.

Comment: thanx for your support... but is there not any way to upgrade ROM by fitting extra ROM as we are doing With PC RAM Size ??

Comment: @Paresh Mayani: Most mobile devices are not designed to be field upgradable, and the HTC Hero certainly fits that description.

Comment: @Paresh Mayani: Applications are installed in the on-board flash storage, except for Android 2.2, where select applications can be installed to "external storage" (typically an SD card).

Comment: thanx and i know about that feature of Android 2.2

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this question is rather old, but many low-end devices suffer from the lack of RAM (e.g. my friend's Samsung Galaxy NEXT Turbo)

First: you need Root to use this. Nothing complicated, no custom rom, just root.

There is a very nice application which uses an SD card as Pseudo-ROM. It is called Link2SD https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD

You would need an application to partition the SD card with 2 partitions: FAT32 and EXT4 / EXT2

More details here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1432459
and the free partition software from partitionwizard.com

Shrink the primary partition, make a new one in the empty space, set BOTH to active, and use Link2SD from your phone to manage your enormous new amount of RAM